# Why does localhost not resolve to 127.0.0.1 on a given port?

Tags: networking

I have an httpd server running on port 80 and [shiny-server](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/) running on port 3838.  When I try `curl 127.0.0.1:3838` I get the index file being served on the shiny-server.  But when I try `curl localhost:3838` curl times out without retrieving any content.  Why?

Here are the contents of my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
<my-ipv4-address> www.<mywebsite>.com <mywebsite>.com
<my-ipv6-address> www.<mywebsite>.com <mywebsite>.com
```

and the results of `getent ahosts localhost`

```
::1             STREAM localhost
::1             DGRAM  
::1             RAW    
127.0.0.1       STREAM 
127.0.0.1       DGRAM  
127.0.0.1       RAW
```

Comment: Usually services like `httpd` need to be bound explicitly to an interface address __or__ to a hostname. But this can vary implementation to implementation.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I am running shiny server on the second port.  Edited the question.

Comment: What do you get if you do `curl localhost:9999`?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor `curl localhost:9999` times out

Comment: Guess: Shiny-server doesn't like IPv6. What happens if you do `curl -g -6 "http://[::1]:3838/"`?

Comment: @dirkt `curl -g -6 "http://[::1]:3838/"` also times out without giving output

Comment: Just wondering what the output of `getent ahosts localhost` is.

Comment: what about `curl -4 localhost:3838`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes! `curl -4 localhost:3838` gives the index page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from `getent ahosts localhost`, the IPv6 entries for localhost take priority over the IPv4 entries. (See `man getent` and `man nss` if you want to know why this command helps).

Curl is dual stack and can resolve both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses, so it uses the IPv6 address. But shiny server doesn't work with IPv6, so it times out, as verified when using the IPv6 address directly. OTOH, if you use `127.0.0.1`, this is an IPv4 address, so it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how your shyni server is listening exactly (ipv4 or pv6 or both)
with :

```
netstat -pantu |grep LIST
```

It must be problem related to a restriction with the use of "localhost" maybe...

Answer (score 0):

To fix it add to `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost shiny myWebsiteName
```

(well append it to the existing line).

---

Even better.

Configure you webserver to listen on `127.0.0.2`, then add to `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.2 shiny myWebsiteName
```

(tested on Debian 8 and 9)